# How to to copy hierarchyid subtree

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, hierarchyid

I want to copy a subtree e.g.

[image]

into the same table, at the next free most-right spot (in this case at /5/...).

Is there any stored procedure which may help me do this? If not: how would I do it?

I'm relatively new to SQL so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those values look like [hierarchyid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-ver15) values which makes this fairly easy. Here's what I came up with:

```
declare @foo table (
    h hierarchyid
);

insert into @foo (h)
values
    ('/4/1/'),
    ('/4/1/1/'),
    ('/4/1/1/6/'),
    ('/4/1/1/7/');

select h.ToString(), 
    h.GetReparentedValue('/4/', '/5/').ToString()
from @foo;
```

The first two statements are just setup (which, incidentally, will make future questions you ask here more likely to be answered if you provide it yourself!). The last bit shows moving the subtree to a new parent.

To avoid having to hard-code the `/5/`, I came up with this (based on the same setup as above):

```
declare @root hierarchyid = '/';
select @root.GetDescendant(
        max(h).GetAncestor(
            max(h).GetLevel()-1),
            NULL
        ).ToString()
from @foo;
```

This is an informed guess as I don't know your actual data. But that should get you a long way there.

Lastly, to actually *change* your data to reflect the values that I'm selecting, you'll have to run an `update` statement. I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Thank you for the support and feedback! I will post more formalized questions in the future.